# SharePoint central administration can't be reached

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration

I have been unable to access the SharePoint server central administration page for almost a month.

The central administration page worked very well. But for a month, the SharePoint sites and the central administration page stopped working.

The last modification I had to make is the change of the password of the administrator account.
The problems started after and I don't know what to do.

---

**Update**:

SharePoint Configuration Wizard error message displayed:

Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
This is a critical task. You have to fix the failures before you can continue. Follow this link for more information about how to troubleshoot upgrade failures: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=866803

> An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown. Additional exception information:
> Upgrade [SpContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] failed.        (EventID:an59t)
> Exception: The upgraded database schema doesn't match the TargetSchema  (EventID:an59t)
> (EventID:an59t)
> Upgrade Timer job is existing due to exception: Microsoft.Sharepoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: The upgraded database schema doesn't match the TargetSchema*

Comment: First of all run Sharepoint Configuration Wizard and if you have an error please provide us with error message.

Comment: Would be fairly poor server configuration but is that admin account being used for SharePoint services and connection to the content database server? Changing the password of a service account would cause a lot of problems.

Comment: @CallumCrowley, Yes, this is the account used for the services as well as the database. Indeed I am looking for a way to update the new password for sharepoint services. I have already updated the password at the database level.

Comment: @PiotrSulowski OK I will try it right now

Comment: Likely that you'll need to run the SharePoint configuration wizard to recover things. I would highly recommend that you use multiple service accounts e.g. a service account for accessing the database server etc, instead of one admin account for everything. The farm administrator account shouldn't be used for any services.

Comment: @PiotrSulowski  at the end of Sharepoint Configuration Wizard here is the error message displayed

Comment: @CallumCrowley I just posted the error message

Comment: Run this in powershell "Get-SPContentDatabase | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase" and then run Sharepoint Configuration Wizard again.

Comment: I solved the error with the tutorial available on this link
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/fix-the-upgrade-database-error-while-running-sharepoint-configuration-wizard

And Sharepoint Configuration Wizard no longer displays an error

But when I access Sharepoint Central Administration, I have an error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @PiotrSulowski, Yes, that's the command I used but when I access Sharepoint Central Administration, I have an error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to access SharePoint central administration through URL.
2. Since you may have the problem by changing the password of the administrator account, I suggest you run the configuration wizard again as administrator. Do not disconnect from the server or do any name mangling, keep everything the same.

Comment: I just posted the error message

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error with the tutorial available on this link
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/fix-the-upgrade-database-error-while-running-sharepoint-configuration-wizard

And Sharepoint Configuration Wizard no longer displays an error

But when I access Sharepoint Central Administration, I have an error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED